# How to write a Sql query in Jpa repository?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am trying to display a set of records from database based on user's search request.I dont think there is a predefined method in JPA repository for this.Hence i would like to write a query in repository for this.

But during build, there is an exception stating as "IllegalArgumentException".

Can someone help me to write a proper query? If there is a better way of doing it, let me know.

The loanReport in the argument is an object which has the user's search request

```
    public interface LoanReportRepository extends JpaRepository<LoanReport, Long> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<LoanReport> {
    public final static String GET_LOAN_REPORTS = "SELECT * FROM loan_report  WHERE product=loanReport.product";

       @Query(GET_LOAN_REPORTS)
    List<LoanReport> findByPreference(final LoanReport loanReport);

}
```

Comment: That isn't JPQL. Read any JPA documentation to see that. Spring has some "native" flag if you really want to put SQL in (and throw away database independence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke JPQL query like this,

```
public interface LoanReportRepository extends JpaRepository<LoanReport, Long> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<LoanReport> {

public final static String GET_LOAN_REPORTS = "SELECT lr FROM LoanReport lr WHERE product = :product";

@Query(GET_LOAN_REPORTS)
List<LoanReport> findByPreference(@Param("product") product);
```

Here `product` can be a value that directly stored in a DB column or another JPA Entity. In latter case entity's identifier will be mapped with the `LoanReport`'s foreign key constraints.

And you can invoke `findByPreference` by passing the `product` property directly like this.

```
 loanReportRepository.findByPreference(loanReport.product);
```

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) for more information. Documentation is pretty good.

P.S.

As far as I know there is no built-in way to pass just an object and expect all/some of its property values to be mapped to entity fields and then to DB level columns.

Another option is to use Spring Data JPA provided dynamic queries that with all the fields you want to search with. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for information

If you want to use multiple fields in search query, best option is to pass all those possible parameters as method parameters and map them to query's parameters. This approach would additionally allow you to sanitise or convert user parameter value into a different format that may be stored on the DB level.

Comment: i am not going to send only one search option(product), there are four more fields, thats why i sending it as an object.What  should i do in that case? And what is that 'lr' mean in the query?

Comment: @Danny I have updated the answer that will answer your question. The SQL query is in written in [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language). You can also use native SQL query if you want with NativeQuery option. `lr` is an alias to `LoanReport ` entity to be used in other parts of a JPQL query.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following code if you use sql

```
public interface LoanReportRepository extends JpaRepository<LoanReport, Long> , JpaSpecificationExecutor<LoanReport> {
    public final static String GET_LOAN_REPORTS = "SELECT * FROM loan_report  WHERE product = :product";

       @Query(GET_LOAN_REPORTS,nativeQuery=true)
    List<LoanReport> findByPreference(@Param("product")final String prouduct);    
}
```

Comment: Correct is 
@Query(value = GET_LOAN_REPORTS, nativeQuery = true)